# How does Windows 10 upgrade to the next release?

Tags: windows-10, upgrade

What is the usual way to upgrade to the next available Windows 10 release?  Is it supposed to be part of a normal Windows Update?

I ask because I recently upgraded a Windows 7 computer to Windows 10 using installation media with the 1809 release.  I (naively?) expected the next Windows Update to get the 1903 release, but it did not.

Does this mean there is a specific reason why the 1903 release was not installed?  Perhaps some component of my computer is as yet incompatible with the new release, or my centrally-managed organization has not approved the new release yet?

Or is upgrading to a new release a manual operation?

Comment: " Is it supposed to be part of a normal Windows Update?" Yes

Comment: Is there a way to investigate why Windows Update did not get the 1903 release?

Comment: MS rolls out the releases to different people as they see fit. Not all computers get the same updates at the same time. You just have to be patient until it's your turn. [Patience is a virtue.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-1809-update-deleted-all-files-from/ff608374-2686-4a08-a4c2-caa4caa6d4e1)

Comment: @JohnGordon - 1903 has indeed been released via Windows Update.  As of today only seekers will upgrade to 1903 through Windows Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MS has again postponed that release](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3387437/microsoft-move-to-release-windows-10-1903-in-may-marks-third-straight-delayed-upgrade.html), and is only pushing it to early adopters. If you'd like to be a test subject, you can check for updates and *choose* to get it.

That said, [a  number of incompatibilities](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/22/all-existing-issues-with-windows-10-version-1903-may-2019-update/) has surfaced, e.g., AMD RAID driver issues. In some cases, v. 1903 might be uninstallable, such as an [issue with some Intel drivers.](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-v1903-upgrade-blocked-due-to-some-intel-drivers/) So install at your discretion. *Caveat usor*.

[Here is a list](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-1903-now-available-to-everyone-via-manual-update/) of some *known* outstanding issues:

- Dynabook Smartphone Link app borked
- Bluetooth broken
- Brightness control bricked
- Dolby Atmos audio busted
- Camera app on the blink
- Wi-Fi connection is brittle

Work has been ongoing to fix issues, but new ones have been found, e.g. [Windows Event Viewer custom views are broken](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-v1903-v1809-updates-break-event-viewer-custom-views/).

That said, there have been a number of issues with the previous release, v. 1809, which as of June 14, 2019, is being re-released yet again, with more problems, such as [black screen after installation](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/06/18/windows-10-black-screen-startup-issue-after-installing-latest-patches/).

Comment: That's a very old article.

Answer (score 2):

There is more up to date information than the article posted in the other answer.

Microsoft is currently doing a rolling release of 1903, slowly pushing the update to computers it deems most ready in order to identify and resolve issues before pushing it to everyone.

They've also published a bug tracker site to keep up with all the identified and squashed bugs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903

Finally, there are ways to manually get the update and these methods are well published, but it boils down to "you have to want it to get it" right now: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update

As you found, just installing Windows 10 right now will get you the version Microsoft deems ready and appropriate for your computer.